# Implementing $http.post in angular JS with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms, http-post

I'm trying to send the message, name and email from a contact form on my index page to my own email but am having some troubles. I'm using AngularJS. Right now when I click submit on the form, it just comes up with a loading screen and nothing else ever happens. This is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="save()" class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded" ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="message.name" />
            <input class="input email" required="required" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your Email" ng-model="message.email" /><br />
            <textarea class="textarea" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Your Message" ng-model="message.text" ></textarea>
            <button class="btn green">Send Message</button>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.save = function () {
      $scope.loaded = true;
      $scope.process = true;
      $http.post('sendemail.php', $scope.message).success(function () {
          $scope.success = true;
          $scope.process = false;
      });
    };
```

PHP (sendemail.php):

```
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$email = $request->message.email;
$name = $request->message.name;
$message = $request->message.text;

$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
$subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

I've also tried the following php:

```
var_dump($_POST);die();
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$email = $_POST["message.email"];             //$request->message.email;
$name = $_POST["message.name"];                     //$request->message.name;
$message = $_POST["message.text"];          //$request->message.text;

$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
$subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

Should the php be in the same folder as the javascript? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks very much.

Comment: What does the var_dump line give you? Also - you may be aware of this, but the `die();` right after will prevent anything else in your second PHP example from running.

Comment: I get a 404 error:

Comment: "POST /sendemail.php" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: That means the http function in Angular can't find your sendemail.php file. Make sure your path to the file is correct (you can make it an absolute path if you need to) and run it again.

Comment: thanks, that should have been obvious i guess. now however it seems like the var_dump doesn't give any line? the contact form just stays in the loading position, and I don't get any error in the CMD

Comment: this is the path i'm using: http://localhost/app/js/sendemail.php

Answer (score 0):

You making POST ajax request, so in order to use data that you're trying to transfer to your PHP application, you need to find it in $_POST array. More about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

More specifically you don't need this line `$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");`

You just need to get data from `$_POST`. Just make `var_dump($_POST);die();` to debug what's in there and what you need to decode exactly.

Comment: Thanks but I still cant seem to get it to work. I've tried a few different things. This is what i currently have (php):

Comment: var_dump($_POST);die();
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$email = $_POST["message.email"];             //$request->message.email;
$name = $_POST["message.name"];                     //$request->message.name;
$message = $_POST["message.text"];          //$request->message.text;

$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
$subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);

Comment: apologies for the bad formatting, i'll edit the question with the updated php. should the php be in the same folder as the js?